# Centering absolute element in hero image both horizontally and vertiaclly

Tags: css

how can i set text (Absolute) position center horizontally and vertically in hero image. i have mentioned my css below

```
.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;     
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Please do not submit code only answers. Explain it!